# Maven profile and properties

Tags: maven, properties, profile

We use maven (version 3.3.9) and define versions of libraries we use in a properties secion. For that we use a properties and dependancy definition like this:

```
<properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <version.foobar.webjar>1.6.0</version.foobar.webjar>
</properties>
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>de.foobar</groupId>
        <artifactId>webjar</artifactId>
        <version>${version.foobar.webjar}</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

This works nicely, the dependency is loaded in the configured version 1.6.0.

However, if I now add profiles that contain completely different properties like such:

```
<profile>
    <id>testing</id>
    <properties>
        <test213>blabla</test213>
    </properties>
</profile>
```

and activate that profile, the "version.foobar.webjar" is no longer set and compiling fails.

Also, when I put the "version.foobar.webjar" definition in a profile like this:

```
<profile>
    <id>testing</id>
    <properties>
        <version.foobar.webjar>1.6.0</version.foobar.webjar>
    </properties>
</profile>
```

and activate the profile, it also does not work. My best guess is, that properties used within a pom-file have to be in its own properties section and cannot be in a level below (like in a profile).

But that still does not explain to me, why properties in a pom don't work anylonger, if I define completely different properties in a profile.

I suppose, I misunderstand http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-profiles.html
that properties add up through the different levels, but I fail to see how I can define properties and have profiles with properties in one pom-file.

I hope, someone can help me out here, because I'm lost.

Comment: Why do you need to change the version of a dependency via property? What is the purpose of this?

Comment: we are doing exactly what you described and it works definitely. we also override properties in profiles (i.e. in a OS specific windows profile), the one's from the root level are taken as well into account. A difference that we have is that dependency versions are defined in the dependencyManagement section. In dependencies itself we only say what we want without adding version once more.

Comment: Please add your complete POM file, maybe there is just something defined on the wrong level.